# How to pass an argument with spaces to sed command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the below function in my shell script

```
fnChangeTxt()
{
        sed -i 's/<div id="'$1'"><p>*.*</<div id="'$1'"><p>'$2'</' /var/www/html/alarm.html
}
```

I would like use the below the pass a string to the sed command via $2 argument.

```
fnChangeTxt 'demo' 'This text to sed'
```

Hoever this doesn't work and produces and error, I assume it is due to the white spaces as the below command works fine.

```
fnChangeTxt 'demo' 'This_text_to_sed'
```

Is there a way to do this with spaces?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `*.*` is probably not doing what you think it is.  eg, the first `*` allows the `>` preceding it to be repeated zero or more times.

Comment: You do not need to repeat the matching pattern.  Try `sed "/\(<div id=\"$1\"><p>\)[^<]*/s//\1$2/g"`.  Note that you need to ensure that neither `$1` nor `$2` contain `/`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell if I use that I get sed: -e expression #1, char 54: cannot specify modifiers on empty regexp

Comment: What is the value of $1 and $2 that raises that error?  Which character is char 54 depends on their value.  Possibly one of them contains a metacharacter.  Or perhaps it is a sed version issue, although this appears to be compliant with http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the parameters (`$1` etc) in double-quotes to keep them from being word-split (and prevent some other possibly unpleasant extra parsing):

```
sed -i "s/<div id=\"$1\"><p>*.*</<div id=\"$1\"><p>$2</" /var/www/html/alarm.html
```

Comment: Thanks, but the double quotes are there because the html requires them and If I put in 2 sets of double quotes it doesn't work.

Comment: I should clarify -- there are two sets of double-quotes involved, one for the shell's consumption around the entire sed argument including the parameters (`"s/...$1...$2.../"`), and a second set that's part of the HTML being substituted (`<div id="...">` etc).  The second set is included in the command I gave, escaped (i.e. preceded by backslashes) so that the shell will ignore them and pass them to sed as part of its argument.

Comment: I understand now, thanks for taking the time to explain. All working fine now. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

try using escape characters:

```
fnChangeTxt 'demo' 'This\ text\ to\ sed'
```

Comment: It doesn't work because the shell parses escapes (backslashes) before doing variable substitution.  By the time it replaces `$2` with `This\ text\ to\ sed`, it's too late for the escapes to do anything useful.